# Equivalence in definition of quasi-Frobenius ring

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, abelian-categories, projective-module, injective-module

A *quasi-Frobenius* ring is defined to be a ring which satisfies the following conditions (I'm phrasing it with left modules, but it's the same with right modules):

(i) $R$ is Noetherian and self-injective (as a left $R$-module)

(ii) All projective left $R$-modules are injective

(iii) All injective left $R$-modules are projective.

It is claimed on wikipedia and other sources that those 3 conditions are equivalent.

I know how to prove that (i) implies (ii), but I'm quite clueless about the rest.

I have some specific situations in mind (e.g. the group algebra of a finite group over a field) where I can prove that they're all satisfied, but the situations are especially nice : for instance, assuming (ii) in some situations I can get that any injective module is a submodule of some projective module, in which case (iii) follows easily, but beyond that I have no clue.

Maybe some duality theory could help me, by considering say $\hom(M,I)$ for some injective module $I$, but I'm not getting anywhere with this.

I'm also wondering how specific to rings this is :

> Let $C$ be an abelian category where all projectives are injective. Is it necessarily the case that all injectives are projective ? What if we have enough injectives/projectives ? Maybe a projective generator ?

And independently :

> How can we see that conditions (i) through (iii) are equivalent for a ring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that (ii)+(iii) implies (i), firstly since $R$ is a free module over itself it is projective, so therefore injective by (ii). It is a theorem that if arbitrary direct sums of injective left modules are injective then $R$ is left Noetherian. This is proven [on page 471 here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-097-03/S0002-9947-1960-0120260-3/S0002-9947-1960-0120260-3.pdf). Since the direct sum of projective modules is projective, and injectivity and projectivity are equivalent in our case, we are done.

<s>If we look at the characterisations of projectivity and injectivity via the splitting of exact sequences then the symmetry and equivalence of (ii) and (iii) becomes clear.</s>

Then since you can show that (i) implies (ii) we are done.

I'm sorry I can't be more helpful as far as the categorical questions are concerned.

**Edit:** My reasoning for the equivalence of (ii) and (iii) was incorrect, but a proof of the equivalence of these characterisations is given as Theorem 24.20 in Algebra II Ring Theory by Carl Faith.

Comment: I understand your first paragraph, but the second one is not so clear to me. I understand how it would prove the equivalence between "every module is projective" and "every module is injective", but I don't see how it helps here - would you care to expand on it ?

Comment: Apologies you're quite right, I'll try and come back with an explanation

Comment: It seems that proving the equivalence of (ii) and (iii) is difficult, I can't find a source that does it directly. However it looks like a full proof of these characterisations is given as Theorem 24.20 in Algebra II Ring Theory by Carl Faith. Unfortunately I only have access to a few pages via Google Books, but I hope the reference is helpful

Comment: Thank you, I do have access to that reference ! You can edit your answer to add the reference and I'll accept it

Comment: You're very welcome, it's an interesting result I haven't seen before so thanks for asking the question!